# In jQuery how to set an option as selected dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Looks like i have a strange problem. I'm creating a select menu and assigning it to some plugin named select menu

```
$('#selectCombo').selectmenu({style:'dropdown'});
```

After assigning it to it.. I couldn't hide it, or set an option as selected. I tried this

```
$('<option value='+ret.cId+' selected=true>'+ret.cName+'</option>').appendTo('#selectCombo');   
    $('#selectCombo').selectmenu({style:'dropdown'});
```

Its working but it is showing another instance of dopdown below the original one. I tried removing class attribute but it hasn't worked. Is there any way.. plz help

Comment: Presumably, [this plugin](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/) is the one you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Custom Select Menus** normally create a `<div>` structure of the original `<select>` element to allow custom styling.

That means that the custom select menu won't know about the changes you've made to the original `<select>`.

Call `.selectmenu('destroy')` before calling `.selectmenu({style: 'dropdown'});` again.

**i.e.**

```
var newOption = $('<option value='+ret.cId+' selected=true>'+ret.cName+'</option>');
$('#selectCombo').append(newOption).selectmenu('destroy').selectmenu({style:'dropdown'});
```

**[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/3B3Fp/)**

Comment: Yeah I tried that previously.. but its showing another instance of the drop down..

Comment: By d way how to remove an option from the select menu.. And also the element "selectCombo" is not working..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can hide by following

```
$('#selectCombo').next('.ui-selectmenu .ui-selectmenu-button').hide();
```

and to set option as selected use this.

```
var value = <your value to select>;
$('#selectCombo').selectmenu("value", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = "anyvalue";
$("#selectboxid").val("value");
```

[check this](http://jsfiddle.net/anupam/GGJ7w/)